# Can not Authenticate Google users from an Ionic App, gets a "Couldn't sign you in" error

Tags: ionic3, google-oauth, cordova-plugins, google-signin, inappbrowser

We have implemented an ionic application that uses Google Authentication to retrieve the Calendar details of the Google account.

For that what we do is, open a browser window from the Ionic application and direct the user to the authentication page.

For some Google accounts this working fine. But for some accounts, we get the below error.

I also tried allowing access for "Less secure apps".

I also observed that this works for some GSuite accounts and do not work for some GSuite accounts. This also happens for private accounts(Personal) as well.

Is there any suggestions or information regarding this issue?

[This error occurs just after we enter the email and proceed.]

[Link to the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fyOz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have a `OverrideUserAgent` preference in your config.xml? you might be using an outdated user agent.
try replacing it with this for android:

```
 <preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-A205U) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.181 Mobile Safari/537.36" />
```

or this for ios:

```
<preference name="OverrideUserAgent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1" />
```

Comment: This works perfectly with Android. But when it comes to IOS it does behave differently. For example, the content of the ionic button normally get converted to uppercase with Ionic3. right? This is not happening in IOS.

Comment: try other iOS user agents:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/ios?utm_source=whatismybrowsercom&utm_medium=internal&utm_campaign=latest-user-agent-index
Typically, in your config.xml you want to have two different OverrideUserAgent, one will be under <platform name="android">, and the other one will be under <platform name="ios">
Sadly, this doesn't for me and I'm not sure why, the OverrideUserAgent property only works when placed outside the platform tag, inside the widget tag.
so i have to replace the line manually each time i build for a different platform

Comment: also, consider migrating to a native solution
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using a browser that doesn't meet the requirements for Google authentication. You can learn more about this here: https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/guidance-for-our-effort-to-block-less-secure-browser-and-apps.html